# Position circles around a circle given x circles with fixed diameter in SASS

Tags: sass, trigonometry

A question of two parts:

End goal is something like this, ala graph DB visualisers - but in html / css/sass
[image: End goal]

Part 1: How to position x number of circles around a circle so the edges touch (or prefereably, with a little whitespace).
For example, this is what i'm going for given 3, 6 and 7 circles. 
I'm trying to get it working using SASS, however if there's a library or something that does what I'm after i'd rather use that - i'm just struggling to formulate the search phrase.

[image]

I'm using the trig functions from [here](https://www.unindented.org/blog/trigonometry-in-sass/), and stole the circle arrangement from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/placing-items-circle/).

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/ollyboly/pen/ExYoGyP) of what I've got so far.

I'm bad at maths, but some friends gave me the fomula you'll find below that should work out the distance to the outer circle center. `$distance: tan((180-($angle))/2) * $radius;`. However its not doing as i expect - given 6 circles, with a diameter of 100 I'd expect an output of 100, but i'm getting 86.602...

Here's the sass - probably easier to look in the codepen though.

```
      @function strip-unit($number) {
        @if type-of($number) == 'number' and not unitless($number) {
          @return $number / ($number * 0 + 1);
        }
        @return $number;
      }

    @mixin on-circle($item-count, $circle-size, $item-size, $break-at) {
      position: relative;
      height: $circle-size;
      padding: 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      list-style: none;

      >* {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: $item-size;
        height: $item-size;
        margin: -($item-size / 2);

        $angle: (360 / $break-at);
        $rot: 0;
        $prevLayer: 0;

        @for $i from 1 through $item-count {
          $layer: ceil($i/ $break-at);
          $layerMinusOne: $layer - 1;
          // MoveX figured out by aligning stuff by eye
          // item-count 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10 ...12    13   14...20
          // moveX (%)  57  70  85 100  115 130 145 160   192   207  225  315
          $item-radius: strip-unit($item-size) / 2;

          // !! This is where i'm having trouble
          $distance: tan((180-($angle * 1deg))/2) * $item-radius;
          @debug "tan((180-#{$angle})/2) * #{$item-radius} = #{$distance}";

          $moveX: ( $distance / strip-unit($item-size)) * 100 * 1%;
          @debug "moveX: #{$moveX}";

          @if $layer != $prevLayer {
            $prevLayer: $layer;
            $rot: $rot + $angle/2;
          }

          &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
            transform:
             // !! This is where the 'percent of circle diameter' measurements come in, translateX uses the size of the element being transformed when % is used. 
              rotate($rot * 1deg) translateX($moveX * $layer) rotate($rot * -1deg);
          }
          $rot: $rot+$angle;
        }
      }
    }

    $numOfCircles: 3; // <- Change me in the codepen 
    .circle-container {
      @include on-circle($item-count: 28, $circle-size: 200px, $item-size: 50px, 
    $break-at: $numOfCircles);
      margin: 5em auto 5em;
      border: solid 5px red;

      .around-a-circle {
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: solid 1px #118be1;
      }
    }
```

Part 2: The extra layers.

My end goal as seen above is to display x number of circular elements in rings, where the inner most ring is made up of y elements and bubbles out from there.

As i said i'd rather use a library, but i couldn't find anything that does what i want. I was going to use the inner ring as a starting point and each alternating layer, rotate an extra bit and place the element nestled between the previous rings elements, but again i'm struggling with the dimensions, and how much to offset by.

```
 $layer: ceil($i/ $break-at);
...
 @if $layer != $prevLayer {
    $prevLayer: $layer;
    $rot: $rot + $angle/2;
  }
```

The above code does that, mostly, however the spacings aren't optimised and the whitespace is too much compared to my end goal photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance needs to be between center of circle 1 and center of circle 2 and half that is your radius for all the circles.

I don't know sass so here is a working JS version as proof that this works.

https://jsfiddle.net/hk5spy20/

If you change line 32-33 from

```
var x1 = pointXY[0].x;
var y1 = pointXY[0].y;
```

to

```
var x1 = xPos;
var y1 = yPos;
```

You will replicate what you are currently doing which results in overlapping circles.

***** Added *****

The way you have the 2nd, 3rd, 4th level bubbles working will become gappy as you expand out because of the radius of the circle increases in size.

It won't work this way.

I have something but require work but I have this so far... https://jsfiddle.net/hd7qp06b/2/

I think for each row you will need two different set of formulas to get this working perfectly, the second row works, the 3rd row doesn't which is where a new formula is required. Will come back to this.

This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/eo170zsu/

You have to keep a track of pair adjacent bubbles and attachBubble next to it. If you put the co-ordinate of bubble 9 and 15 on the stack, it'll place new bubble perfectly next to it. However, you can't put bubble 9 and 16 on stack as well because this would cause an overlap. There is a sequence of pairs that are safe and probably be consistent for certain levels, I suspect odd / even levels has different rules for pairing.

Actually, thinking about it, just pair 9,15 and 9,16 process each one and if there is an overlap between two circles on screen, throw it away and try next pair.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solution takes the large red circle radius as an input and works out the radius of the smaller circles. Ideally, i'd like to define the size of the smaller circles only, and work out the position of everything else relative to this... is this possible?

Comment: Scale the final output to the size you want - Made a slight tweak to previous fiddle - See https://jsfiddle.net/ptj192uf/

Comment: Change first line to set the desired circle radius required. As for the red circle, you can delete all references to it including variables. var x = Math.cos(radians) * redCircleRadius; would become var x = Math.cos(radians); The red circle was just for my reference to see it is working

Comment: Using your answer and some fiddling, i've managed to implement your suggestions in SASS, which works as your JS version does (with slighty overlapping circles and all). https://codepen.io/ollyboly/pen/BaBrPay

Comment: And here's a version with the layering added back ( https://codepen.io/ollyboly/pen/aboYjrx)  - i'll probably give up at this stage with part 2! Thanks for your help

Comment: Added more code that should solve your multiple layer issue for part 2. Also the slight overlap is caused by DIV not coping with half a pixel correctly so you have it rounding to nearest pixel and it is not the formula as the reason why it overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for the extra code, for what i was planning i think its far too complex to comvert into SASS, if i ever come back to this and make it a JS solution i'll be sue to check this out first. I'll mark your answer as accepted as you've been most helpful!

Comment: Turned out to be far easier than originally thought - here is a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/u0L5prwv/ you can see a pattern which means you don't have to do complicated maths after all. Anyway, if you view the console.log() output you can copy and paste the CSS for all the positions. Set minGapBetweenCircle if you want to add more gap between circles.